# Angular 1.2 Animation Classes never applied to view

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations, angularjs-animation

I'm having difficulty with applying animations to my ng-view. The ng-enter and ng-leave classes don't ever seem to be applied to the view. The behavior seems to be the same as not having animations. Is there any way to verify that the animation functionality is actually working, so I could tell if this is a problem with my code or the way I have angular loaded?

html:

```
<div ng-view class="fade"></div>
```

css:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade.ng-enter,
.fade.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.fade.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fade.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fade.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: have you injected the ngAnimate module and $animate service?

Comment: From the resources I can find it doesn't seem to be neccesary to load ngAnimate as a module of the application for Angular > 1.2. Attempting to do so gives me an error, I assume because it's no longer intended to be.

Comment: Whoops - indeed I did, but that wasn't my issue. I was using an old (though > 1.2) version of Angular with the newest version of the angular-animate module - hence why it failed to load as a module.